# Object has no attribute - python class execution

Tags: python, class, object, methods, attributes

I've searched for an answer to this problem, but I can't find an answer, it may be too specific.

I have a simple program, my first proper program and I've created it mainly as practice:

```
import math

class Logs(object):

  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def apply_log(self):
    self.a_log = math.log10(self.a)
    self.b_log = math.log10(self.b)
    return (self.a_log, self.b_log)

  def add_log(self):
    self.log_add = self.a_log + self.b_log
    return self.log_add

  def log_split(self):
    self.log_c = self.log_add // 1
    self.log_m = self.log_add % 1
    return(self.log_c, self.log_m)

  def result(self):
    self.ex_m = 10 ** self.log_m
    self.ex_v = 10 ** self.log_c
    self.log_res = self.ex_m * self.ex_v
    return self.log_res

lg = Logs(34,54)
#print(lg.apply_log())
#print(lg.add_log())
#print(lg.log_split())
print(lg.result())
```

The program runs perfectly when I uncomment out all the print statements and run them at the same time. However, if I just want to print the result for the instance and comment out the three other print statements, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 33, in <module>
  File "python", line 24, in result
AttributeError: 'Logs' object has no attribute 'log_m'
```

I don't understand why it would work when printing out the results of each method or why this would affect how the program would run.

I'll also say right now that this is the first time I've used a class (the point of the program was practice for creating a class) so I imagine the error is in the way I've created it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you are calling `lg.result()` before `self.log_m` gets created. removing your commented out prints works fine...

Answer (score 4):

It has to throw the `AttributeError` because `log_m` is initialized in the method `log_split` and used in the method `result`. If you call `result` without calling `log_split` before, `log_m` is not defined and you get the error that you are seeing. This class is designed in a way that `result` can only be called after `log_split`.

Answer (score 0):

log_m is a local variable inside your log_split(self) function.

So inside the result(self) function, the log_m and log_c are two variables unknown to the function.

So you have to run log_split() first and then result().

Answer (score 0):

The value of `log_m` is initialized in `log_split` method, and it is dependent on the value of `log_add` which is initialized in `add_log` method. Moreover, `log_add` is dependent on the value of `a_log` and `b_log` which are initialized in `apply_log` method. Hence, it shows the  `AttributeError` when you comment all the three implementations of the methods.
You have to maintain the sequence of method calling, otherwise commenting any of the methods will cause the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way of maintaining the call sequence without printing? Or perhaps a redesign of the class is needed...

Comment: you can simply remove the print statement, it will work just fine.